# Правильно ли написан JS? И стоит ли вообще так делать?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function margin() {
  var product4 = document.getElementById('product4');
  var containerCatalog = document.getElementById('containerCatalog');
  var styleOfcontainerCatalog = getComputedStyle(containerCatalog);
  if (styleOfcontainerCatalog.width < '1180') {
    product4.style.marginRight = '1.2%';
  };
};

margin();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.section_title {
  margin-top: 34px;
}
.section_title  h2 {
    color: #2f1127;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .underline {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3fa9f5;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: 18px;
  }

 .catalog_products .product {
   background-color: #f6f6f6;
   width: 23.73%;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 1.2%;
   min-width: 280px;
  }
  .catalog_products #product4 {
   margin-right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<section class="catalog">
  <div class="container" id="containerCatalog">
    <div class="section_title">
      <h2>Каталог</h2>
      <div class="underline"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="catalog_products">
      <div class="product">
        <div class="background_place background_place_1"></div>
        <h3>a</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <div class="background_place background_place_2"></div>
        <h3>a</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <div class="background_place background_place_3"></div>
        <h3>a</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id='product4'>
        <div class="background_place background_place_4"></div>
        <h3>a</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <div class="background_place background_place_5"></div>
        <h3>a</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <div class="background_place background_place_6"></div>
        <h3>a</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть 6 блоков, 280px допустим, нужно сделать так что бы при уменьшении контейнера блок переходил на новую строку, если он влазит. Задал блокам свойство `display:inline-block` при максимальной ширине контейнера в строку влазит 4 блока, я дал всем блокам правый отступ что бы они занимали всю ширину контейнера, но последнему элементу строки не дал. Выходит что если он перейдет на новую строку при уменьшении контейнера у него не будет правого отступа, тогда блоки слипнутся, я написал код, который будет добавлять правый отступ к этому блоку, когда контейнер будет меньше своей максимальной ширины.

Вопрос в том, хорошо ли код написан, нормальная ли это практика использовать для адаптива JS, и можно ли было это сделать с помощью css?

Comment: Не путайте резину и адаптив,и зачем грузить дополнительно js,когда можно сделать css...

Answer (score 1):

Проще использовать контейнер flex. Вот упрощенный пример:

```css
.catalog_products {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product {
  flex-basis: 280px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog_products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="background_place background_place_1"></div>
    <h3>a</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="background_place background_place_2"></div>
    <h3>a</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="background_place background_place_3"></div>
    <h3>a</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product" id='product4'>
    <div class="background_place background_place_4"></div>
    <h3>a</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="background_place background_place_5"></div>
    <h3>a</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="background_place background_place_6"></div>
    <h3>a</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: И все же: у последнего элемента в ряду есть отступ:    http://prntscr.com/hsdql2 если я его уберу, то при переходе на новую строку, у этого элемента не будет отступа и он слипнется: http://prntscr.com/hsdrkg 

Допустим я это через медиа поправлю, ну а если будет допустим несколько таких колонок.

Comment: Я думал, он нужен справа, этот отступ. Если не нужен отступ, уберите `margin` у блоков, а родителю добавьте свойство `justify-content: space-between`, например

Comment: В общем, это один из вариантов сделать резиновые блоки. Вот статья про flexbox: http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/ . Если этот контейнер и не подходит, все равно, в любом случае использовать js - плохая идея.

Comment: Решил свою проблему при помощи css grid

Comment: Ну да, как вариант. Grid кажется не до конца еще всеми поддерживается, но можно и пренебречь https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid